# Unable to update images in PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QSlider, QLabel
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from utils import read_screenshots

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "PyQt5 Slider"
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 500
        self.width = 1400
        self.height = 1300

        self.InitWindow()
    
    def InitWindow(self):
        # hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap('./screenshots/output000011.png'))
        self.label.setGeometry(60, 60, 1280, 720)
        
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.slider.setTickInterval(1)
        self.slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.slider.setMaximum(100)
        self.slider.setGeometry(100, 830, 1000, 20)
        self.slider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changedValue)

        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)

        # self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()

    def changedValue(self, value):
        # change value of the slider when you move the slider and switch to the next img
        if value == 0:
            print(value)
            self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap('./screenshots/output06439.png'))
        elif value < 50:
            print(value)
            self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap('./screenshots/output025316.png'))
        else:
            print(value)
            self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap('./screenshots/output033238.png'))

        size = self.slider.value()
        self.label.setText(str(size))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

My changedValue() function is printing the values correctly but it doesn't display any of the images based on the value conditions. The changedValue() is supposed to switch pictures. Where have I made a mistake?

I couldnt figure out what the problem is!

Comment: A QLabel can either display text **OR** an image, not both. In your code you're calling `setText()` after `setPixmap()`, so the label will show the text.

Comment: @musicamante I commented out         # size = self.slider.value() # self.label.setText(str(size)). But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Maybe the image path is not correct or the file is not a valid image. Check the paths and ensure that you're not running the script from a different directory, because relative paths are **always** relative to the "working dir" (so, it's possible that you have a `output000011.png` file in the path from which the script is run, but the other images are not there). Also, [`width()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#width-prop) and [`height()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#height-prop) are *existing* properties of **all** Qt widgets, and you shall not overwrite them.

Comment: On the property overwriting: I know that some tutorials suggest to do that, but they are *wrong*, as they don't consider this important aspect. Existing attributes should **NOT** be overwritten unless you *really* know what you're doing. Besides, setting instance attributes makes sense only when they're *actually* being used more than once and outside the function scope. And 99% of the times I've seen this, it doesn't justify that usage. Always check the "List of all members, including inherited members" link in the class documentation to ensure you're not overwriting important attributes.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. Something to do with the path. Thanks for the help @musicamante

Comment: @CJSSSSS You can write up an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer